# How to remotely control an android phone without using the screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, broken-screen, 8.0-oreo

Ok Today I got a problem where something looking like a blue ink stain progressively leaked inside the screen in 6 hours until things turned from blue to completely black until nothing can be displayed anymore.

The touch screen still works so I can still do things like doing a phone call, but I don't remember anything else for accessing apps or other menus.

I have usb debgging on and all Samsung/google remote control operations enabled (but as far I'm aware they don't allow full control). I also have teamviewer installed but it's not configured.

Because the point is the phone is connected to Internet. I need to go back home today and I need the gps for it. Local sellers don't have the screen before 3 weeks.

However, I have a second tablet but it's WiFi only. If I could find a way to remotely enable WiFi tethering (or with spoken commands) things could a lot of easier.

## Update :

Now it’s not only the phone which has a problem, but the car does no longer run (as the engine is burning it’s own oil).
And has young driver still on bail, I can’t rent anything.

Though I’m still interested on how to solve such kind of problems in the future.

Comment: You can setup Tasker or MacroDroid or some other automation app to enable tethering on target device when receiving a certain trigger. The trigger can be a voice command (might need AutoVoice app too) or an SMS with certain keywords is received, or anything that suits you.

Comment: @Firelord and does setting that kind of thing requires using the broken screen ? Remember that some permissions need to be manually enabled using the screen in Oreo. Because such apps aren’t installed.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot the main issue of having a broken screen. Does your target device has support for OTG? If yes, you can use a mouse with an OTG cable to setup those automation apps in the target device. This assumes that the broken screen still shows something. If it doesn't, my advise wouldn't work.

Comment: @Firelord though I can still start and stop the tablet. And install app with permissions if they are required before install. They are still auto start apps on Android Oreo (I mean apps which start automatically on start‑up even without setting special permissions after installing or having ever started the app manually). I can also use ᴀᴅʙ over ᴜꜱʙ. **The touch screen still works perfectly as described in the question, so it’s not about using the known Bluetooth mouse I have in Bluetooth settings but to know where buttons are displayed**.